# Azure Application Gateway Slash Rewrite Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, load-balancing, azure-application-gateway

We have created an Azure Application Gateway using path-based rules to redirect requests of clients to servers on the background pool based on the client instance name, like this:

```
"/client1/*" -> Server1
"/client2/*" -> Server2
"/client3/*" -> Server1
```

When we make requests to http://mygateway.azure.com/client1/, it works fine and Server1 returns the expected page. But, when I left out the ending slash `/`, like http://mygateway.azure.com/client1, the Server1 can't be found and the page is not returned. It looks like Application Gateway can't resolve the url during the rewrite operation.

I've tried severeal settings to the path in the ApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings like "`/client1`", "`/client1/*`" and "`/client1*`", but it didn't work.

Have you ever seem this problem?

Tks

Comment: This could possibly be related to the trailing-slash redirect problem stated in this [issue-link](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/458)

Answer (score 0):

Azure Application Gateway does not currently support URL Rewriting, [but we are looking to add the feature in the future](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/12239826-support-url-rewriting-with-application-gateway).

When creating your URL Routing rule, Each must start with / and the only place a "*" is allowed is at the end following a "/." The string fed to the path matcher does not include any text after the first? or #, and those chars are not allowed here.

You will most likely have the specify the exact page or file that you want to access.

Comment: The URL rewrite feature is now available - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url